# Assigning output of zenity to a variable

Tags: bash, unix, zenity

I have a script that makes a GUI list here:

```
zenity  --list --text="Choose action" --column= --hide-header opt1 opt2 opt3
```

How can I make this output be assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
OUT=$(zenity --list --text="Choose action" --column= --hide-header opt1 opt2 opt3)
```

This will assign the output to `$OUT`.

The `$()` operator performs [Command Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_04), i.e. allows the output of a command to replace the command itself.

Comment: the presence/absence of `--hide-header` shouldn't make a difference to the answer (and is not a valid option on older versions of zenity) :p

Comment: Well, it would make *the answer* different by `--hide-header` :) And yeah, i have no idea what this option is about, just spotted the difference.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker fine. I'll oblige :D

Comment: Damn, but now there's a scroller :( :)

Comment: You're just as pedantic as I am! Scroller dealt with.

Comment: :) (no, there still is a scroller on my browser, but nevermind, I appreciate your striving for perfection).

Comment: Note that not all shells support the `$(command)` syntax for command substitution.  Modern Bourne-derived shells do, but the older backtick syntax is an alternative.  It's `‘command‘` (but with real backticks).

Comment: Note that this method is also the way to process multiple form fields from `zenity` (option `--forms`).  It is up to you to split this single string into multiple variables, and the `--separator` option helps.